# Why does this trigger comma-dangle rule in eslint?

Tags: eslint

This looks correct to me, but why does eslint show a rule violation, missing trailing comma `comma-dangle` at the end of the last property "credentials"?

```
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER,
    payload: credentials
  });
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-quotes": 0,
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-double"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the `airbnb` config the rule is setup like this
`comma-dangle: [2, "always-multiline"]`.

Acoording to this, The `expected` code is

```
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER,
    payload: credentials,
  });
```

It expects a `,` at the end.

More info on rule: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle

Comment: that seems like an odd rule, what is the stylistic reason behind that?

Comment: There are many options. You can always set the option to `never`. That way it work for your code.

Comment: from react up and running "Dangling commas (as in let a = [1,] as opposed to let a = [1]) can be considered bad (as they were a syntax error once upon a time in certain browsers), but they’re also convenient, as it helps maintain source control “blame” and is easier to update"

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/@nikgraf/why-you-should-enforce-dangling-commas-for-multiline-statements-d034c98e36f8) topic explains it a bit

Answer (score 10):

I use the following combination (this works for me)

**[1] .eslintrc.json**

```
"rules": {        
        "comma-dangle": [2, "always-multiline"]         
    }
```

**[2] JsPrettier | Prettier**

```
"trailingComma": "all"
```

**Results**

```
dispatch({
  type: LOGIN_USER,
  payload: credentials,
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the below rule to avoid it

```
rules: {
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never']
  }
```

//or

```
 "comma-dangle": ["error", {
        "arrays": "never",
        "objects": "never",
        "imports": "never",
        "exports": "never",
        "functions": "never"
    }]
```

reference: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle